# Admin page MVC conventions

Tags: admin-pages

What is the convention when creating MVC admin pages in sitecore?

What routing is used, where are controllers and views placed?

Comment: What do you mean by "admin pages"? Pages which are accessible for sitecore administrators under /instance/sitecore/admin url or admin pages for visitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you can create an item (or a whole structure) in your content tree for admin pages as well.
You get:

- Item permissions to manage  access to various admin pages
- You can store settings/configurations on these items
- Get versioning/workflow for these data
- Utilize the rendering pipeline of Sitecore

Unless you have very unique requirements, I don't think you should separate these pages from Sitecore's other aspects.

Answer (score -4):

You can place .cshtml files in your site's /sitecore folder or subfolders and browse to them directly by filename, e.g. http://mysite.com/sitecore/my-folder/my-file.cshtml. I haven't seen this documented anywhere, but it works.

I don't know how you'd do it with an actual MVC controller class.